# systemd - automatically start/restart specific systemd service after another service is started/restarted

Tags: systemd

As in subs - I want to start/restart b.service after a.service is started/restarted.

Is there a nice way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `PartOf=`

From https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html: 
Configures dependencies similar to Requires=, but limited to stopping and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts the units listed here, the action is propagated to this unit. Note that this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the listed units.

Comment: If `b.service` has `PartOf=a.service`, then restart a seems to trigger (1) stop b, (2) stop a, (3) start b, (4) start a. To change also add `After=a.service` to `b.service`